# How to label one point bigger than all others in a layer?

Tags: qgis, vector, labeling

I have a point dataset in one layer. I labelled all points but I would like to label one point larger size than other point labels. How can I do it?

[image]

Merzifon and Bahçecik are in the same point layer. I want "Merzifon" text larger size than "Bahçecik".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **Rule-based labelling** to specify the parameters of individual or groups of points. You can do this by *right-clicking the point layer > Properties > Labels*. Then select the options as shown in the image:

[image: Labels]

Now you can add rules to specify how *'Merzifon'* should be displayed by editing the properties such as size and colour:

[image: Rule properties]

Then repeat by adding another rule for *'Bahçecik'*.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with an expression for the size in the labelling dialog.

First click the expression button at the far right of the size setting - here its yellow because its active (at first the button will look like the others):

[image]

Then set it to something like this, depending on what size you want and the name of the attribute of your towns - here I want London labelled at size 24 and everything else at size 9:

[image]

This will get complicated if you have a lot of towns with different size labels. Create a new attribute column in your layer called "LargeLabel" or something, and set to 1 for those you want labelled large, and adjust the expression accordingly.

If you want to label towns with large populations larger, and you have "population" in your layer attributes, you can do something like `if(population>100000, 24, 9)`  to label them with larger text.

If you want to scale label sizes according to the value in the dialog, you can use `@value` in an expression. This expression will set London in text which is 3 times the size of the "9.000" in the dialog box, and other labels in size 9.000 - and if I change the "9.000" everything scales up or down proportionally:

```
 @value * if(name='London',3,1)
```

Comment: I would have answered as @Joseph but didn't know about the possibilities you give here. Thanks!

Comment: @wiltomap - Agreed, personally I think this is a much more efficient solution that what I posted =)